# Rename columns with similar strings - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have a pandas df that contains where the first two columns represent the other cols. However, the specific strings will change depending on the input data. So I want to use the strings and replace with the other columns.

Using the df below, we have similar col names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Foo_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],  
        'Bar bar_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],                               
        'GroupA_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],                   
        'GroupB_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],  
        'GroupA_some_other_string' : ['X','X','X'],                   
        'GroupB_some_other_string' : ['X','X','X'],  
                })
```

Intended Output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Foo_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],  
        'Bar bar_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],                               
        'Foo_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],                   
        'Bar bar_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],  
        'Foo_some_other_string' : ['X','X','X'],                   
        'Bar bar_some_other_string' : ['X','X','X'],  
                })
```

I **can't** use `df.rename` here because `foo` and `bar` will be variable in that they'll change depending on the input dataset. For example, the first two col values could be `Dog` and `Cat`.

I would have to manually determine the `col values` and then replace. This becomes inefficient if I have to complete the process numerous times.

So I need something that isn't hard-coded but takes the first two `col values`.

Comment: Your input and output column names are confusing. Please simplify.

Comment: Does my answer answer your problem? You can try some variant of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
groups={'GroupA':df.columns[0].split('_')[0],'GroupB':df.columns[1].split('_')[0]}
for group in groups:
    df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(group, groups[group])
```

Comment: Cheers. Thanks @Sameeresque

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to replace using a dictionary but see if this would work -

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Foo_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],  
        'Bar bar_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],                               
        'GroupA_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],                   
        'GroupB_somestring' : ['X','X','X'],  
        'GroupA_some_other_string' : ['X','X','X'],                   
        'GroupB_some_other_string' : ['X','X','X'],  
                })
rename_dict={'GroupA':'Foo', 'GroupB':'Bar bar'}
new_col= [re.sub('|'.join(rename_dict.keys()), lambda x: rename_dict[x.group()], i) for i in df.columns.to_list()]
df.columns = new_col
```